# The static variables cant be seen

Tags: java, class, static, actionlistener

I have different files for different panels in my code, and I want to add a file for the action listener. I have declared my variables as static so the action listener can see them but it doesn't see them.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Respuestas extends JPanel{

    static JRadioButton cb1 =new JRadioButton("1");
    static JRadioButton cb2 =new JRadioButton("2");
    static JRadioButton cb3 =new JRadioButton("3");
    static JRadioButton cb4 =new JRadioButton("4");
    static JRadioButton cb5 =new JRadioButton("5");

    public Respuestas(){

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));

        this.add(cb1);
        this.add(cb2);
        this.add(cb3);
        this.add(cb4);
        this.add(cb5);

        Manejador manejador = new Manejador();
        cb1.addActionListener(manejador);
        cb2.addActionListener(manejador);
        cb3.addActionListener(manejador);
        cb4.addActionListener(manejador);
        cb5.addActionListener(manejador);
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.swing.*;

class Botones extends JPanel{

    public static JButton sig = new JButton("Siguiente");

    public Botones(){

    this.add(sig);

    Manejador manejador = new Manejador();
    sig.addActionListener(manejador);

    }
}
```

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Manejador implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evento) {

        if(evento.getSource()==sig) {                 //Error
            System.out.println("Siguiente");
        }
        else if(evento.getSource()==cb1) {            //Error
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        else if(evento.getSource()==cb2) {            //Error
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        else if(evento.getSource()==cb3) {            //Error
            System.out.println("3");
        }
        else if(evento.getSource()==cb4) {            //Error
            System.out.println("4");
        }
        else if(evento.getSource()==cb5) {            //Error
            System.out.println("5");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: " i have declared my variables as static so the action listener can see them" Hmm... do you really understand the usage of the [`static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to declare your variables as public:

```
public static JRadioButton cb3 =new JRadioButton("3");
```

and to read that value you have to call it from the class like this:

```
Respuestas.cb1;
```

your actionPerformed method should be like this:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evento) {

    if(evento.getSource()==Botones.sig) {                 //Error
        System.out.println("Siguiente");
    }
    else if(evento.getSource()==Respuestas.cb1) {            //Error
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    else if(evento.getSource()==Respuestas.cb2) {            //Error
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    else if(evento.getSource()==Respuestas.cb3) {            //Error
        System.out.println("3");
    }
    else if(evento.getSource()==Respuestas.cb4) {            //Error
        System.out.println("4");
    }
    else if(evento.getSource()==Respuestas.cb5) {            //Error
        System.out.println("5");
    }

}
```